# How to handle slow IPN response?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-nvp

I have a website which allows users to pay using paypal.  I use paypals IPN to find out if the payment was successful or not.

Everything works fine as long as the complete, cancel, pending, failed etc ipn responses are quick.  However, I need to stop users from paying more than once if paypal is slow at sending an ipn response.

For example, if paypal is going to send a complete response, in which case it will not send a pending response.  If paypal takes 5 minutes to do that.  How do I stop users from paying twice within those 5 minutes?

Comment: record their 'attempt' to pay locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I usually use PayPal:

1. Complete order page, that **doesn't** contain the PayPal form.
2. The complete order form redirects to an internal page, that saves the order, and generates the PayPal form. **You can do your custom logic here.** (ie. check if the user was already sent to PayPal in the last 5 minutes, etc).
3. The above step should generate the PayPal form with every bit of information that will be sent to Paypal. Note that everything will be hidden from the user, except a submit button. Click that submit button with javascript, so the user will be redirected to PayPal, but as a fallback, do a 5 second timer, and inform the user to click the button if he's not redirected in 5 seconds.

That's it, don't forget to send the order number you saved locally to PayPal in the `custom` field.

Before proceeding, be aware of the following: If a user is redirected to PayPal - but closes the window, you have no way of knowing if the order will be payed or not. If he clicks cancel, you can send to PayPal a cancel url, where you will receive the information and mark the order as cancelled.

**PS:**

In step 3 you can tell the user you already have a pending order from them, and they should only proceed if they don't want to pay the previous order.